How to separate the string by specific symbols and write it to list?
I have the following string:
my_string='11AB2AB33'
I'd like to write this string in a list, so 'AB' is a single element of this list in the following way:
['1', '1', 'AB', '2', 'AB', '3', '3']

I tried to do it by
list(my_string)

but the result wasn't what I expected:
['1', '1', 'A', 'B', '2', 'A', 'B', '3', '3']

I also tried partition method:
list(my_string.partition('AB'))

and also didn't get expected result
['11', 'AB', '2AB33']


Perhaps something like print(re.findall(r'AB|\S', my_string))

@Thefourthbird, it is exactly what I need!! Thank you so much!!

Can your my_string also contain other characters? Or only characters A-Z or digits without spaces?

@Thefourthbird, in my particular case only A-Z characters or digits) but it would  be also interesting consider the case with spaces)

You can use re.findall with an alternation using the pipe | matching either AB or a non whitespace character \S If you also want to match spaces you can use a . instead of \S
You can see the matches here on regex101.
my_string='11AB2AB33'
print(re.findall(r'AB|\S', my_string))

Output
['1', '1', 'AB', '2', 'AB', '3', '3']


If you want to use split, and you only have characters A-Z or digits 0-9, you could use non word boundary to get a positon where directly on the right is either AB or a digit.
You can see the matches here on regex101
my_string='11AB2AB33'
print(re.split(r"\B(?=AB|\d)", my_string))

Output
['1', '1', 'AB', '2', 'AB', '3', '3']

